# При очистке дополнений пропадает контент

Tags: opencart

День добрый друзья. Такая проблема, когда в дополнениях жмешь очистить - пропадают некоторые модуль (а именно: Complete SEO, NewsBlog и еще некоторые)
После чего нажимаю обновить кеш - все появляется, и еще глюк, когда очищаю меняется вид категорий товаров, обновляю - ввозвращается все назад, кто сталкивался с такой бедой(
А еще если очистить то перестают работать сео ссылки, будто модуля нет вообще
Подскажите что может быть, для теста могу дать доступ

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно. Используя Ocmod вы, а точнее движок, создаёт копии тех фалов, которые затрагивает устанавливаемое расширение. Когда вы совершаете очистку, все эти файлы физически удаляются. Поэтому там есть ещё одна кнопка - обновить. Нажимайте и её после очистки. Она делает то же, что и перезагрузка страницы. Ну и модули, конечно, тоже дают глюков. Даже платные часто написаны на скорую руку, что приводит ко всякого рода непоняткам. Так же Ocmod - неиссякаемый источник конфликтов между расширениями. Поэтому всегда ставьте модули/расширения по одному и тестируйте,тестируйте...

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, проблема была в модуле Layered Navigation Ajax by Plaza Themes
Отключил его и все заработало, спасибо всем